# django update object with form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-1.6

in django 1.6, I have a model with

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastname = name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and a form

```
class EventPerson(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['name', 'lastname']
```

if I create a object with

```
p = Person.object.create(name='John')
```

and I have a dictionary

```
d = {'lastname':'Smith'}
```

how I can update the object with the dictionary and the form ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that with the least code would be with the class based `UpdateView`.

Here is the link to the Django Docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView

A **views.py** code sample would be:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from myapp.models import Person

class PersonUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Person
    fields = ['name', 'lastname']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

Then just add the form in your **template**. By default the template name will be `person_update_form.html`

The **template** code just looks like:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This will also automatically populate the form with any initial form data from the `Person` object that you are trying to update.

**Edit:**

To update an object based on a dict of the object you want to:

- get the object

  `person = Person.object.get(name='John')`
- update it

  `# if this is the new lastname
  d = {'lastname':'Smith'}`

  `# then access the dict and update it
  person.lastname = d['lastname']`
- save the object

  `person.save()`

You don't need to use the form if you are not using a template.

Comment: I use the form in a management command, I can't use a template

Comment: yes, I know update like `person.lastname = d['lastname']` but my problem is more general, in the question only need update one field, but in real case I have more fields. I like use form for create objects because I can use methods like `clean`, `clean_`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If your model doesn't have inherited attributes you can use:

```
p.__dict__.update(d)
p.save()
```

You can use this in the form's `__init__` also